# Circuit breaker compatibility

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci

I have a T&B 200 amp panel TBB20 and I need to add a 50 amp 240 volt GFCI circuit for an EV charger.   Code requires that the circuit be GFCI.   What 50amp 240volt circuit breaker is classified or approved for a T&B panel.

Thanks Jim

Comment: No. Code only requires the circuit be GFCI **if it is wired to a receptacle, because, the receptacle might be used for other things**.  If the EVSE is hardwired, no GFCI breaker is required (a disconnect is, but they're cheap).  Further, putting a "dumb GFCI" on an EVSE is foolish because EVSE's already *by law* include a "smart GFCI" which the EVSE controller will self-reset so you get a charged car in the morning.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine  make this an answer. It should pop up again.

Comment: Can we see a quality photo of the panel labeling?  It will have several sections and one will list the allowed breaker types. T&B was one to have their panels cross-listed to use certain competitor breakers, because they didn't want to develop oddball breakers in-house (e.g. tandems, shunt trip, HID or whatnot).

Comment: Yes, can we have a photo of the labeling on the inside of the panel door please?

Comment: My understanding is there isn't a *Listed* GFCI breaker available for that obsolete panel. If hard wiring is not an option for you then an awful alternative is an Eaton CL250 is *classified* as a TB250 replacement, use it to feed a small sub-panel or spa disconnect with GFCI breaker mounted near the panel or receptacle that then feeds the receptacle. Also check with local AHJ to verify adoption of 2020 NEC and exceptions.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease -- there are *Classified* CLxxxGFT breakers, but they're only available in single pole